# Iterating over bless objects in Perl

Tags: perl, variables, iteration

I'm working on some code to query F5 load balancers using the BigIP::iControl module.

Right now, I'm getting the following output when doing a Dumper on a variable I get back from a particular function.

I've having a lot of trouble iterating of this object.

How could I go about iterating over this and only taking out the monitor_status for each member?

```
$VAR1 = [
          bless( [
                   bless( {
                            'monitor_status' => 'MONITOR_STATUS_UP',
                            'member' => bless( {
                                               'address' => '127.0.0.0.1',
                                               'port' => '8085'
                                             }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' )
                          }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberMonitorStatus' ),
                   bless( {
                            'monitor_status' => 'MONITOR_STATUS_UP',
                            'member' => bless( {
                                               'address' => '127.0.0.0.1',
                                               'port' => '8085'
                                             }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' )
                          }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberMonitorStatus' ),
                   bless( {
                            'monitor_status' => 'MONITOR_STATUS_DOWN',
                            'member' => bless( {
                                               'address' => '127.0.0.0.1',
                                               'port' => '8085'
                                             }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' )
                          }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberMonitorStatus' ),
                   bless( {
                            'monitor_status' => 'MONITOR_STATUS_DOWN',
                            'member' => bless( {
                                               'address' => '127.0.0.0.1',
                                               'port' => '8085'
                                             }, 'Common::IPPortDefinition' )
                          }, 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberMonitorStatus' )
                 ], 'LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberMonitorStatus[]' )
        ];
```

Comment: Object::Iterate is a module that allows you to use `map` and `grep` with an object.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether those member variables are public - I'm not familiar with the modules used - so this might well violate the encapsulation of the `LocalLB::PoolMember::MemberMonitorStatus` class.  You should check before using.

```
for my $mms ( @{$VAR1->[0]} ) {
    warn $mms->{monitor_status};
}
```

It would be better to check whether the MemberMonitorStatus class provides an accessor, and possibly an iterator for the member monitor status array.

The above was tested simply by pasting your Dumper output into a Perl script with the code of the for loop implemented based on eyeballing the data structure.

***(edit:*** *based on F5 webcentral docs in the Google cache, it may be that MemberMonitorStatus is a simple struct in the underlying code, exposed in the Perl as a class with two member variables - but no behaviour.  If so, the above is probably OK.)*